# Can I tell through Python API whether a property is used when it depends on another property?

Tags: python, properties

Can I tell through Python code (Blender 3+) whether a property is actually used when it is controlled by a different (parent?) property setting? For example, in Mask Modifier, **Armature** pointer value only shows and is relevant if the **mode** is set to *Armature*. If it is set to *Vertex Group*, can I tell that **Armature** field is not relevant?

I saw is_hidden value in rna definitions, but they don't seem to change when I switch mode.

Is there some sort of hierarchy between properties?

[image: Mask Modifier]

Comment: I don't think so, afaik the armature object is still tied to the modifier even when you set it to Vertex Group afterwards, (otherwise you'd lose the link if you inadvertently changed the mode for example) the only difference is the object field is not displayed (and it's not actually used in the modifier logic, obviously)

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "not relevant".  If you simply mean "not currently used by the modifier" then you've answered your own question: you tell by seeing what the mode value is; as far as I know.

Comment: @MartyFouts , my question is about how to tell *from Python* what I see visually. Which set of fields is linked to specific mode setting and - even if set - is not actually due to changed mode setting.

Comment: My comment was direct to telling from Python.  You use Python to get the modifier from the modifier stack, and then you read the modifier's settings to see whether it's set to Vertex Group or Armature.

Comment: @MartyFouts I appreciate the effort, but it does not seem to be answering the question I was trying to ask, about dependency between modifiers. It now seems that this information is not in RNA, but is in the UI code. So there may not be a good answer.